# Warnings of .js file not found... I added a login template in my project and after running program there comes two warnings

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net, .net

**1**.

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Warning   TS6053   (JavaScript) File 'F:/2020
> projects/StudentPortal/Views/Logins/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js' not
> found.    StudentPortal JavaScript Content Files  F:\2020
> projects\StudentPortal\Views\Logins\Registration.cshtml   1   Active

**2**.

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Warning   TS6053   (JavaScript) File 'F:/2020
> projects/StudentPortal/Views/Logins/js/main.js' not
> found.    StudentPortal JavaScript Content Files  F:\2020
> projects\StudentPortal\Views\Logins\Registration.cshtml   1   Active

Comment: As per the error, 2 files are missing from the locations. Have you checked jquery.min.js and main.js is present at respective locations.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added js file in your html file? just like this:

```
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
</body>
```

Note：The location of JS file is relative to HTML file, and do not write it as absolute position. If you write the absolute location, the code will be invalid after moving the file.